# Regex to match a word or a dot between words (optionally) in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently working on an issue that matches a word between special characters. Optionally matches words in between dot.

I currently tried below regex pattern it works fairly well in words that have dot in between but I struggled to make it work with word without dot.

```
[^\W\s]+\.+[^\s\W)]+
```

Given the string:

```
  ,DECODE(T3.ATEST,' ',T3.BATEST
                           ,DECODE(NVL(T4.BATEST,'9') 
                                 ,'1',NVL(T4.BATEST,' ')
                                     ,T3.BATEST))
```

it matches the following:

```
T3.ATEST
T3.BATEST
T4.BATEST
T4.BATEST
T3.BATEST
```

Now trying this regex pattern above without dot in between:

```
  ,DECODE(ATEST,' ',BATEST
                           ,DECODE(NVL(BATEST,'9') 
                                 ,'1',NVL(BATEST,' ')
                                     ,BATEST))
```

I need a regex that also has the output below:

```
ATEST
BATEST
BATEST
BATEST
BATEST
```

Is it possible to optionally match a words between dot?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is there anything specific about those strings you need to capture? For example, a specific pattern of letters and numbers, a specific ending or length?

Comment: Maybe `/(?:\w+\()+|(?<!')\b(\w+(?:\.\w+)?)\b(?!')/g`? will do? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zaH2xv/1), only keep the Group 1 values. Or, without a lookbehind, `/(?:\w+\()+|\b(\w+(?:\.\w+)?)\b(?!')/g` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/zaH2xv/2))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as I checked the demo, it works perfectly but when I switch to Javascript, the group1 values are no longer present. Would there are modifications needed to make this work on javascript?

Comment: Nothing changes, the Group 1 values are all there.

Comment: I run the first regex pattern through string.match(pattern) and it returns an array like this ["DECODE(", "T3.ATEST", "T3.BATEST", "DECODE(NVL(", "T4.BATEST", "NVL(", "T4.BATEST", "T3.BATEST", "DECODE(", "ATEST", "BATEST", "DECODE(NVL(", "BATEST", "NVL(", "BATEST", "BATEST"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?:\w+\()+|\b(\w+(?:\.\w+)?)\b(?!')/g
```

If your JavaScript environment supports ECMAScript 2018+, you may use

```js
/(?:\w+\()+|(?<!')\b(\w+(?:\.\w+)?)\b(?!')/g
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/zaH2xv/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/zaH2xv/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\w+\()+` - match one or more sequences of one or more word chars and then `(` char
- `|` - or
- `\b` - match a word boundary
- `(?<!')` - `'` is not allowed to be immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\w+(?:\.\w+)?)` - Group 1: one or more word chars and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and then one or more word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!')` - not followed with `'` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = ",DECODE(T3.ATEST,' ',T3.BATEST\n ,DECODE(NVL(T4.BATEST,'9')\n ,'1',NVL(T4.BATEST,' ')  ,T3.BATEST)) ,DECODE(ATEST,' ',BATEST ,DECODE(NVL(BATEST,'9')   ,'1',NVL(BATEST,' ')    ,BATEST))";
const regex = /(?:\w+\()+|\b(\w+(?:\.\w+)?)\b(?!')/g;
let results=[],m;
while(m = regex.exec(text)) {
  if (m[1] !== undefined) {
    results.push(m[1]);
  }
}
console.log(results);
```

If your JavaScript environment supports `matchAll`:

```js
const text = ",DECODE(T3.ATEST,' ',T3.BATEST\n ,DECODE(NVL(T4.BATEST,'9')\n ,'1',NVL(T4.BATEST,' ')  ,T3.BATEST)) ,DECODE(ATEST,' ',BATEST ,DECODE(NVL(BATEST,'9')   ,'1',NVL(BATEST,' ')    ,BATEST))";
const regex = /(?:\w+\()+|\b(\w+(?:\.\w+)?)\b(?!')/g;
const results = Array.from(text.matchAll(regex), x => x[1]).filter(x => !!x);
console.log(results);
```