# Finding words between special characters using Unicode regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a working [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/42meBB/1/) which matches the words below.

Input:

```
(T1.Test)
(AT.Test)
```

Match:

```
T1.Test
AT.Test
```

But when I try replacing `/w` with unicode `\p{L}`, the regex does not work properly anymore.

Current expression:  `/(?:\w+\()+|\b(\p{L}+(?:\.\p{L}+)?)\b(?!')/gu`

Input:

```
(T1.Test)
(AT.Test)
(ワーク.Test)
```

Match:

```
Test
Test
Test
```

How do I make my regex works properly now it has unicode flag?
My expected output should be:

```
T1.Test
AT.Test
ワーク.Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `\p{L}` does not catch numbers, so `(T1.Test)` will not be matched, while with `\w` would be.

Your regex is diveded in two big `OR` parts "`1 | 2`":

1. `(?:\w+\()+` this non capturing group is matching anything of the shape `anyAmmountOfLetter(`. If this has success will totally ignore the rest of the regex, I don't know if it was intentional. This for example will trigger your regex: `aaa(333.6780)` with `aaa(` as full match, but 0 groups as you are not capturing it.
2. `\b(\p{L}+(?:\.\p{L}+)?)\b(?!')` this requires that you start your expression with a word boundary. [But \b is valid in between two characters (Regex Tutorial)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) only if one is a word character an the other is not.

In your case, your starting round bracket will not be matched against the word boundary so `(クーク.Test)` will not work, but `3クーク.Test)` will.

For fix that you can use only the second part (if the first is not really needed for checking something else of what you had shown in the question inputs):

```js
// slight edited, can use digits: (3123.123) => 3123.123
input.match(/[\b]*\(([\d\p{L}]+(?:\.[\d\p{L}]+)?)\)[\b]*(?!')/gu)

// slight edited, must start with letter: (A1.Test) works, (1A.Test) doesn't
input.match(/[\b]*\((\p{L}[\d\p{L}]*(?:\.[\d\p{L}]+)?)\)[\b]*(?!')/gu)
```

Also the last part `\b(?!')` is optional for the input cases you gave, but I suppose it is usefull for other purposes.

If you want to keep the regex simple for those inputs, this would also work:

```js
// can use digits: (3123.123) => 3123.123
input.match(/\(([\p{L}\d]+(?:\.[\p{L}\d]+))\)/gu)

// must start with letter: (A1.Test) works, (1A.Test) doesn't
input.match(/\((\p{L}[\p{L}\d]*(?:\.[\p{L}\d]+))\)/gu)
```

Comment: As for no.1, it is intentional same with no.2. I also tried your regex but it was not working.
For reference, the regex I used was from my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805967/regex-to-match-a-word-or-a-dot-between-words-optionally-in-a-string which works correctly but not unicode characters.

Comment: Ok from the other question I see more details. For me the problem is the `\b` just after the or `|`. Just make it optional `/(?:\w+\()+|[\b]?([\d\p{L}]+(?:\.[\d\p{L}]+)?)\b(?!')/gu` and remind also to include `[\d\p{L}]` for include digits

Comment: Anyway if you are trying to build a parser I suggest to avoid RegEx as much as possible, particularly in cases where you have something like function calls. This can be an usefull resource to fastly build up parsers in JS from simple grammars [PEG.js](https://pegjs.org/)